# UI flow editor Android library

Tags: android, user-interface, iot

I'm looking for a UI library to implement something like Node-RED (https://nodered.org/) in a fragment of my Android application. I need to interact with blocks to build a flowchart which will be used to structure a routine. The user should be able to drag, drop and connect blocks (choosing the types of blocks and connections). I couldn't find much on the internet. Obviously the backend part will be implemented by me, I just need a tool to manage the UI and make it look pleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to build a web app using rete.js (https://retejs.org/) and then include it in my application using a WebView.
It seems there are no native Android libraries that do what I wanted.